# How to install QCL in Windows in order to implement Grover's algorithm?

Tags: quantum-computing

I installed QCL and could run it from command prompt but I couldn't import files. Please help me with the tutorials too if possible. Also let me know how to write codes in editor and compile it.

Comment: Related: [What resources are available for learning QCL?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5374)

Comment: This question is rather broad (three questions in one) and is lacking an [mcve]. Readers are unlikely to be able to help with so little detail. Please edit your question to cut it down to one specific problem, and include enough detail to help readers help you.